# some error with javascript using WebDriver

Tags: c#, javascript, testing, selenium, webdriver

I want to use javascript to locate the controls and send value to it.
For example I want to change the text in the textbox(id="ID") into "123456".

Here comes my code:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('ID').value='TextValue'");
```

but something get error. it show `invalidoperateException`.
Before this I try to use javascript to return the title and it works.

```
string title = (string)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return document.title");
```

I cannot figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I do it:

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ID"));
string setAttrScript = "arguments[0].setAttribute('value',arguments[1])";
driver.ExecuteScript(setAttrScript, element, "TextValue");
```